# How manually plot weekly component in fbprophet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, facebook-prophet

I use fbprophet for making a forecast based on timeseries which I have. Everything is going well apart from the last moment.

```
m = Prophet(daily_seasonality = True, yearly_seasonality = False, weekly_seasonality = True,
                seasonality_mode = 'multiplicative', 
                interval_width = interval_width,
                changepoint_range = changepoint_range)
m = m.fit(dataframe)
forecast = m.predict(dataframe)
m.plot_components(forecast)
```

[Results of plot_components function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rDWU.png)

Instead of using standard function plot_components I need to save data and plot it independently (for example in QuickSight of AWS). I understood how to do it for trend (it takes all possible data and make plot) but I don't understand how it works with weekly and daily graphs.

Has someone idea how to save data for weekly and daily plots?

Answer (score 2):

The daily component is repeated for every day in the dataset, so to plot this you can use:

```
# n = number of readings in 24hr period
forecast['daily'][:n].plot()
```

However, the weekly component is less intuitive. It appears to match that created by plot_components() when you choose the component value at 00:00 for each day. So can be plotted as (provided your data starts on Sunday):

```
# n = number of readings in 24hr period
forecast['weekly'][:n*7:n].plot()
```

Comment: Are these results giving an average week for whole data or just a chosen week?

Comment: An average week for the whole data

Answer (score 0):

Digging through some prophet internals on:
https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/python/fbprophet/plot.py

A way to achieve this is to write your own function, reusing some internal code from `plot_weekly()`

```
def my_custom_plot_weekly(m, ax=None, uncertainty=True, weekly_start=0, figsize=(10, 6), name='weekly'):
    """Plot the weekly component of the forecast.
    Parameters
    ----------
    m: Prophet model.
    ax: Optional matplotlib Axes to plot on. One will be created if this
        is not provided.
    uncertainty: Optional boolean to plot uncertainty intervals, which will
        only be done if m.uncertainty_samples > 0.
    weekly_start: Optional int specifying the start day of the weekly
        seasonality plot. 0 (default) starts the week on Sunday. 1 shifts
        by 1 day to Monday, and so on.
    figsize: Optional tuple width, height in inches.
    name: Name of seasonality component if changed from default 'weekly'.
    Returns
    -------
    a list of matplotlib artists
    """
    artists = []
    if not ax:
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w', figsize=figsize)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    # Compute weekly seasonality for a Sun-Sat sequence of dates.
    days = (pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', periods=7) +
            pd.Timedelta(days=weekly_start))
    # Import this function: seasonality_plot_df 
    df_w = seasonality_plot_df(m, days)
    seas = m.predict_seasonal_components(df_w)
    days = days.weekday_name
    # Return the data here, do not plot.
    return days, seas
```

In your case you would get something like this:

```
m = Prophet(daily_seasonality = True, yearly_seasonality = False, weekly_seasonality = True,
                seasonality_mode = 'multiplicative', 
                interval_width = interval_width,
                changepoint_range = changepoint_range)
m = m.fit(dataframe)
forecast = m.predict(dataframe)
my_custom_plot_weekly(m)
```